# Group by on Key columns and get the records having one valid value and zero value

Tags: oracle, db2

we have a scenario where as per group by key columns i have to get only record having  combination of 0 & any valid number for column "ID"

with the below example

```
TransId,CustomerNm,Date      ,Number,Gender,ID
1      ,Surya     ,2020-01-01,123456,M     ,1234
1      ,Surya     ,2020-01-01,123456,M     ,0
2      ,Naren     ,2020-01-20,123456,M     ,3456
2      ,Naren     ,2020-01-20,123456,M     ,6789
```

When i try with the below query (key columns: TransId,CustomerNm,Date,Number,Gender)

```
select TransId,CustomerNm,Date,Number,Gender from INS.Transaction 
group by TransId,CustomerNm,Date,Number,Gender having count(*) > 1

i will get both the records 

1      ,Surya     ,2020-01-01,123456,M     
2      ,Naren     ,2020-01-20,123456,M
```

but i am trying to get the records having ID =0 . Expecting output as

```
1      ,Surya     ,2020-01-01,123456,M
```

Pls suggest if i can add any change in the above query

Comment: you want the record of `Surya` where the id=0 ??

Comment: @RobertoHernandez .. Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes , as per key columns wherever i have more than count(*) > 1 -- in among those records wherever we have minimum 0 , i am trying to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while doing group by add MIN(ID) in select query and then fetch id  0

```
select * from (
select TransId,CustomerNm,Date,Number,Gender,MIN(ID) ID from INS.Transaction 
group by TransId,CustomerNm,Date,Number,Gender having count(*) > 1 ) where ID = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another `AND` to the having clause to check if `min(id) = 0` . I have renamed some columns.

```
select transid,customernm,transaction_date,some_number,gender 
  from transaction 
group by transid,customernm,transaction_date,some_number,gender 
having count(*) > 1 and min(id) = 0;
```

***Note:- Do not use reserved words as column name like `date` and `number`***